# C# Mouse Movement (WinForm)

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to do this, and I'm in need of some help.

How would you go upon creating this: When you click on a button, the mouse cursor will move to a specific location and then after 3 seconds it will left click and then after 1 second it moves the cursor to a different location?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/e2a4df07-ea48-4c4c-8281-6db1b4247e4b/

Answer (score 1):

Cursor.Position will get or set the position. 
Check out the .NET Cursor class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf27z138.aspx

You can simulate clicks using mouse_event win32 API

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

How to get locations:

```
   Point FormLocation = this.Location;

   Point ButtonLocation = this.button1.Location;
```

Comment: Your troubles will come from screen resolution. I made an app which did this for data farming recently and I built a primitive screen scraper to get button positions and what not. If it's just a personal program you shouldn't have too much trouble though - that or you could just ask the user their screen res?

Comment: Thanks guys, but if I move the form the mouse will move off, so how would I make it move to the location based on the position of the form.

Comment: Where is the button you want to click? Is it on your program, another's program, on a web browser or?

Comment: The button is on the program.

Comment: Your program you are making, or another's program?

Comment: My program, what i'm to achieve is when I click on a button the mouse will move to a location(coordinate) and will click by itself, and after few seconds it moves to another location. I'm having trouble with this :/